# How to get unknown image from folder in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an image that is uploaded to a directory called "uploads" on my server, is there anyway I can display that image on an HTML page without having to specify the filename of the image? Say I want to display the only png image within the directory, is there something like a wildcard that I can use to scan for the image that fits the criteria?

Comment: What use would this ever be? If you are uploading the file you should know it's name. If a random person is uploading the file you can store the name. If you are trying to randomize the picture you can (among other ways) change the name of the file to a number and display a random number.

Comment: Get all the images names in your directly, then filter out the ones you want (in this case check for a `.png` extension).

Answer (score 0):

Using something like the following pseudocode can allow you to pull all the .png files from your `/uploads` folder, thus if you only have one file in question it should work fine. It involves JQuery however.

```
var dir = "S/uploads/";
var fileextension = ".png";
$.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
            $("body").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + "></img>"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Careful, you only want to check the end of the file, otherwise things like `"hello.png.jpg"` would pass.

Comment: I honestly didn't even think of that. I'll adjust my code momentarily, thank you.

Comment: This assumes that a request to a directory returns an array of all files in said directory?

Comment: Yes, it assumes a directory is browsable.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not directly possible as that would create vulnerabilities. You can hack it, as others have answered if you don't care about security.

An alternative would be with scandir() (php)

```
$dir    = '/your-directory-here/';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
```

This outputs an array of the files in `$dir` and you can then sort/isolate however you want. See more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php